# How to add OnItemSelectedListener for one Spinner in multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

In my `ActionBarActivity` I use a `ViewPager` for different `Fragment`s. I use a `Spinner` in the `SupportActionBar` to populate the Fragments in `ViewPager`.

If I write this code in just one `Fragment` the application works as intended. However if I add the same method in the second Fragment as well, the `OnItemSelectedListener` from the first `Fragment` is not called any more.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_names);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onContentChanged(position);
        }
```

Is it possible to share the `setOnItemSelectedListener` of an `MenuItem` amonst different `Fragment`s? Or is there a better way to share the selection of the `ActionBarSpinner` amongst the `Fragment`s of my Application?

Edit:
I have a `TabLayout` with two `Fragment`s.
The `Spinner` is used for a query to filter the results in both `Fragment`s.
I want to update both `Fragments` as soon as the user makes a selection. However I can't register in `OnItemSelectedListener` for both `Fragment`s. Hope this makes it a little clearer. Sadly I can't upload pictures yet.

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve? If it works as intended now, what kind of behavior/answer are you looking for? Also the given code seems to be in Activity, not Fragment?

Comment: My problem is that when I set `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener( new...)` in the second Fragment, the onItemSelected of my first Fragment isn't called any more. I suspect that a `Spinner` can only have one `OnItemSelectedListener`. However I want to update both fragments with the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set one `Listener` to the `Spinner`. You can achieve what you need if the `Activity` that hosts your fragments has access to them.

You could create a nested class in your `Activity` that hosts the `ViewPager` and thus the `Fragment`s. Attach the listener to `Spinner` with a custom constructor that takes the `Fragment`s as parameters

```
class MyListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
     Fragment frag1;
     Fragment frag2;

     public MyListener(Fragment f1, Fragment f2)

     {
        frag1 = f1;
        frag2 = f2;
     }

     @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (f1 != null)
            {
            }
            ....
        }    
}
```

Then in your activity create the listener with

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_names);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyListener(fragment1, fragment2));
```

How well this will work and how easy it will be to create the listener will depend on your implementation of the `TabLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Clever way to avoid trying tohold a permanent reference to a Fragment. I will try and upvote as soon as i got it running!

Comment: You just have to figure out how to get references to the fragments. Proably from the ViewPager. You could even store the fragments in an array in the activity and make your viewPager or adapter to retrieve the fragments from that array in the `getItem()` method. But this is not suitable for a large number of fragments, maybe.. :)

Comment: As it turnes out holding a reference to fragments like this is unstable as android regularerly recycles the fragments leading to a crash from time to time. I didn't notice in the beginning as it happens very rarely.